# Let $A$ be a nonempty bounded subset of $\mathbb R$ and let $B$ be the set of all upper bounds for $A$. Prove that $\sup A=\inf B$

Tags: analysis

Let $A$ be a nonempty bounded subset of $\mathbb R$ and let $B$ be the set of all upper bounds for $A$. Prove that $\sup A= \inf B$. Can someone please help me? I'm very confused as to what to do.

Comment: How do you define $\sup A$?

Answer (score 6):

Well, by definition of supremum, $\sup A\in B$ and for all $x\in B$, $\sup A\leq x$. Then $\sup A=\min B=\inf B$.